# Unable to delete the Azure resource which points to another stale resource

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-private-link

I created a Azure Private Endpoint for a storage account. When I deleted the resource group it seems the storage got deleted first and Private endpoint still points to stale storage account. I could not delete the private endpoint any more.

I cannot delete even with force option.

```
PS /home/user1> Remove-AzResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/subcription-id/resourceGroups/Testing007/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/pe022 -Force
Remove-AzResource: InternalServerError : An error occurred.
CorrelationId: 45bf24f4-7198-4893-9aa0-5cb527874ba7

PS /home/user1> Remove-AzPrivateEndpoint -ResourceGroupName Testing007 -Name pe022 -Force
Remove-AzPrivateEndpoint: Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'An error occurred.'
StatusCode: 200

ReasonPhrase: OK
Status: Failed
ErrorCode: InternalServerError
ErrorMessage: An error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your scenario but would be interested in knowing more about the "internal error". Could you please run the `Remove-AzPrivateEndpoint` cmdlet passing `-Debug` along? Did you see the same error when deleting it from Azure portal?

I also found that clearing the `PrivateLinkServiceConnections` property or updating `PrivateLinkServiceId` manually does not help.

Looks like there was a similar [incident](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/124956/cannot-delete-private-endpoint-connection.html) in the past that was fixed, but I'm afraid reaching out to Support is the only way out if it's a dangling endpoint not fixable from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Bhargavi. Yes I reached to support. They said it is an known issue and helped me in deleting the resource

Comment: @DhamotharakannanV Oh, glad your issue is resolved now, thanks for sharing. Please consider [upvoting and marking it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it also helps others in the community with similar asks. :)